# How do I remove all the <br> and turn them into line breaks (\n) in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

Do I simply do a `replaceWith`?  What's the best way?

```
function replaceBreaks(s){
            var content = $('<div>' + s + '</div>');
            content.find("br").replaceWith("\n");
            return content.html();
        }
```

Comment: Show code or my answer is purple.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result string?

Comment: If you are turning some html into plain text it will be better to interact with string and regexes than jquery functions.

Comment: if you can do this on the server would be best - unless you have a really odd set of conditions :-)

Comment: Okay, so you've dumped some tiny bit of code into the question. Is it not working for you? In what way? What are you seeing? What do you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: I just wanted to ask if this was the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing HTML without an actual HTML parser might be a bad idea, but regular expressions can often be Good Enough.

```
text.replace(/<br[^>]*>/gi, "\n");
```

This will replace <br>, `<br/>`, `<br />`, `<br some_attribute="value" />`, etc etc.

However, it will not replace `</br>`, in case you might have `<br></br>`.  If so, you could try this:

```
text.replace(/<\/?br[^>]*>/gi, "\n");
```

if you don't mind `<br></br>` getting turned into \n\n.

Comment: Just a few thoughts: the reason that processing html with regular expressions is usually considered a bad idea is that there are so many edge cases that are valid html that are very hard or impossible to catch with regex.  But if you have enough control over the content you're processing, a lot of times you can get away with it.

Comment: However, the usual place I've seen a need for what you've asked for in your question is when you have a bit of html content that you want to also use in some kind of tooltip or in an alt= or title= attribute.  If that's your use case here, you're likely to still have html stuff in the resulting text -- paragraph tags, entities like &quot;, etc.  You may wind up better off figuring out a way to process html into plain-text on the server side using a proper HTML parsing library.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
$('br').text('\n').contents().unwrap();
```

First it adds a text node child to all br elements of `\n`. Then it unwraps them leaving only the text below it. You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UgZNm/

Answer (score 1):

I found this regex, which should take care of all kinds of formatting problems:

```
function br2nl(input) {
    return input.replace(/<[bB][rR](\s+)?\/?>/g, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `replaceWith` is the best solution, as well as being clear and easy:

```
$(selector + ' br').replaceWith('\n');
```

Here's a fiddle that shows this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hHJvM/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because `replaceWith` only accepts an HTML string, DOM element, or jQuery object.